# Missing v.in.ogr module of GRASS in QGIS Processing toolbox?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, grass.script

I am a new user to QGIS/GRASS and I am having a problem utilizing GRASS.

I have several files that I generated in QGIS that I want to import into GRASS so I can use some of the Grass modules.

However, I cannot find the v.in.ogr module in the processing toolbox selection.

All I have is v.in.dxf and v.in.wfs.

Is there a module/plugin/extension that contains the v.in.ogr module that I need to download?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: New and related development: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319333/5256

Answer (score 3):

From QGIS 2.10 onwards, GRASS is no longer enabled by default. From the Start menu, you can select to start QGIS **with** GRASS:

[image: Start menu]

When it's loaded, you can open a mapset from the **Plugins** menu:

[image: GRASS options]

To show the GRASS toolbox, right-click on the toolbar to get the menu to enable/disable panels and toolbars and select **GRASS Tools**:

[image: Interface toolbar]

You should, hopefully, see the **GRASS toolbox** in the same place where the *Processing toolbox* appears:

[image: GRASS toolbox]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing two different issues: the Grass plugin (Joseph answer and the new [GRASS Plugin ready](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRASS-Plugin-ready-td5233807.html))  and Grass in the Processing Toolbox:

1) with the GRASS plugin, you work in GRASS GIS and you must use v.in.ogr to import your shapefile in the original GRASS GISDBASE (locations, mapset)  -> The Joseph answer
2) a GRASS script in the processing toolbox creates first a **temporary** GRASS GISDBASE, import the layer with v.in.ogr, do the work **and  finally  destroy this temporary folder** (see [How to modify existing grass gis tools and run them in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103973))

In theory, These GISDBASEs have nothing to do with each other but if you know Python, you can modify the procedure.

Comment: This is very informative, great to know about the new GRASS plugin version!