# QGIS 2.14.1 Processing Toolbox GRASS 7 .NVIZ Not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, nviz

I have a problem with the command GRASS 7 .nviz in QGIS 2.14.1 installed through QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.1-1-Setup-x86_64.exe.md5sum

all GRASS commands work exept .nviz / nviz7

images:

[image]

[image]

I test with both .nviz from grass .nviz / nviz7 from grass7

not know if I'm doing it wrong, but when I run the command, appears complete/finished but without any result or output and not control windows is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute an algorithm in the Processing Toolbox, the result is recorded in the file /.../.qgis2/processing/processing.log

With the command `Nviz7`, the result in the processing.log file is

```
processing.runalg("grass70:nviz7","/path_to/dem.tif",None,None,"202086.577,205625.414407,88411.048,90534.3504441",0)
```

The Python processing module of QGIS uses the module `subprocess` to launch directly the GRASS 7 commands (look at [How to modify existing grass gis tools and run them in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103973/2581) For more complete explanations)

The command executed by GRASS 7 is in the /.../.qgis2/processing/grass7_batch_job.sh or .bat

```
g.region n=90534.3504441 s=88411.048 e=205625.414407 w=202086.577 res=35.3883740678
r.in.gdal input="/path_to/dem.tif" band=1    out=tmp1460281752142 --overwrite -o
nviz7 elevation=tmp1460281752142
exit
```

Therefore, is the command `Nviz7` does not exist in your GRASS 7 installation folder,  no output ("without any result or output and not control windows is displayed")

Answer (score 2):

If run grass7.0.3 standalone nviz module works, and in grass7.0.3/bin there isn't nviz and/or nviz7 binary file!? Seems that nviz7 command is moved in
the ./qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/nviz7.py.